# MongoDB - Find max and min value of timestamp

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find the max and min values of the `myUpdateTime` field. It's a timestamp but stored as a string.

```
"myUpdateTime": "2021-11-08T17:42:30.650Z",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would recommend that you should store the Timestamp value as `Timestamp` rather than `string` to improve the performance in case that every time you need to convert the field into Timestamp such for these scenarios:

- Sort by timestamp
- Filter timestamp by range/compare

To get the min/max of `myUpdateTime`, you have to use `$group` operator to group by all documents. And perform the `min` and `max` value by converting the  `myUpdateTime` into `Timestamp` value first.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      minUpdateTime: {
        $min: {
          $toDate: "$myUpdateTime"
        }
      },
      maxUpdateTime: {
        $max: {
          $toDate: "$myUpdateTime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xAMEWodBHix)

Answer (score -1):

To find the maximum and minimum values of the "myUpdateTime" field, you can convert the timestamp strings to actual Date objects and then compare them.

```
      // Example data
    const data = [
      { myUpdateTime: "2021-11-08T17:42:30.650Z" },
      { myUpdateTime: "2021-11-09T15:21:10.850Z" },
      { myUpdateTime: "2021-11-06T12:35:20.250Z" },
    ];

    // Convert timestamps to Date objects and extract their time value
    const times = data.map((item) => new Date(item.myUpdateTime).getTime());

    // Find the minimum and maximum time value
    const minTime = Math.min(...times);
    const maxTime = Math.max(...times);

    // Convert the time values back to Date objects
    const minDate = new Date(minTime);
    const maxDate = new Date(maxTime);

    // Format the dates as strings
    const minDateString = minDate.toISOString();
    const maxDateString = maxDate.toISOString();

    console.log(`Min: ${minDateString}`);
    console.log(`Max: ${maxDateString}`);
```

Comment: mongodb query ?